# Read from txt file with unknown numbers of int in C

Tags: c, arrays

I have to read "N" int from .txt file and place each one to an array X[i]
But the problem is, I'm not suposed to know how many int are in the txt. The code has to work for every txt following this model

5 4
1 2 3
1 3 4
2 3 5
4 5 5

So I have, in the first line, the second number (4 in the exemple) the number of int in the txt will be N=4*3 (4 lines with 3 numbers (ALWAYS second number*3)) + 2 (first line)
The only code I know how to do is when I know how much numbers, like

```
    int t[14] // I know there are 14 numbers on the .txt
    while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp)) {

  int result = sscanf(buf, "%d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d %d", &t[0], &t[1], &t[2], &t[3], &t[4], &t[5], &t[6],&t[7],&t[8],&t[9],&t[10], &t[11],&t[12],&t[13]);
  if (result <= 0) break;  // EOF, IO error, bad data

  for (r=0; r<result; r++) {
    if (i >= sizeof(X)/sizeof(X[0])) break;  // too many
    X[i++] = t[r]; //put them in the X[MAX]
  }
}
```

And I need to read every number cause like in
2 3 5
I'll place 5 to a array[2][3]
How I am supposed to do this?
Can someone show me an example???
Thanks!

Comment: You will need to allocate the array _dynamically_, probably with the `malloc` library call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple template:

```
int a, b, i;
int *N;
if(fscanf(fp, "%d%d", &a, &b) != 2) { /* Read the first 2 integers */
    /* Unable to read in 2 integers. Handle error... */
}
N = malloc(3 * b * sizeof(int)); /* Allocate enough space */
for(i = 0; i < 3*b; ++i) {
    if(fscanf(fp, "%d", &N[i]) != 1) { /* Read numbers one-by-one */
        /* Input may not be enough. Handle error... */
    }
}
/* Now you have (3*b) integers stored in N */
/* after operations completed... */
free(N);
```

There is no need to read in line-by-line and *guess* how many numbers are there. Just call `fscanf()` again and again since your input is delimited by space characters and newline characters.

Comment: It would be better if you demonstrated `if (fscanf(fp, "%d%d", &a, &b) != 2) { ...handle error... }` and similarly for the `fscanf()` in the loop. Also, for sane sizes of the second number, C99 would allow you to use a VLA (variable length array): `int N[3 * b];`.  Of course, C99 also allows you to interleave statements and declarations, like C++ does.

Comment: The problem is I need EVERY number. It's like 1 2 3  I'll place 3 to a mat[1][2]

Comment: The code will read every number; `scanf()` reads to the end of a number and leaves whatever is not number behind for the next input operation. The loop will read the newline at the end of the first line and then the first number on the second line up to the blank, then the next iteration will skip the blank and read the second number on the line up to the second blank, and so on and so forth. This code won't care if the numbers are all on one line, or one number per line, or if there are twenty blank lines between successive numbers. _[...continued...]_

Comment: _[...continuation...]_  If you must do line-oriented I/O, then you use `fgets()` to read a line at a time and `sscanf()` to read the three numbers from each line: `while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != 0) { if (sscanf(line, "%d%d%d", &N[i], &N[i+1], &N[i+2]) != 3) { ...error... } else i += 3; }` or thereabouts, remembering to check for array overflow (the number said there were 20 lines but there were actually 40 lines; detecting EOF won't help if you've trampled out of bounds).

Comment: "comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]" refering to for(i = 0; i <N; ++i)" And when I try to print the numbers, the .exe explodes

Comment: Edited the loop boundary. It was a typo.